# Unresolved reference: VERSION_NAME Error in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Unresolved reference: VERSION_NAME

how can I solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYgux.png)

Comment: Please share your code as formatted text, not as an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\flutter_paystack-{version}\android\src\main\kotlin\co\paystack\flutterpaystack\MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt:
```

**Changes:**

```
"getUserAgent" -> {
            //result.success("Android_" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + "_Paystack_" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
            result.success("Android_" + "29" + "_Paystack_" + "1.0.0" )
        }

        "getVersionCode" -> {
            //result.success(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE.toString())
            result.success("1")
        }
```

Comment: I can not find this file, can you send me complete address ?

Comment: External Libraries -> Flutter Plugins -> flutter_paystack-{your_installed_version}